# Display a bash script and all its functions in a visual way

Tags: shell-script, text-formatting, images, graph

Is there a tool (general or bash / shell specific) that can display a code into in clean visual representation of the functions.

Like a visual algorithm with bubbles with the name of the functions and different arrows with if, loop....

Comment: To transform bash scripts themselves, or other languages like C, etc?

Comment: sorry, edited i meant "Display"

Comment: like the view you could get in Netbeans or Codeblocks or any IDE ?

Comment: Maybe yes. Is there an Atom plugin maybe ?